# Where did my "edit" checkboxes go?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, view

I just made a new view, and the checkboxes to select files (or select ALL files) have vanished from the view. I still have the drop-down to the right of the document name.

I've been through all the options to look for something I may have inadvertently flagged on my list or a column that defines those checkboxes, but haven't been able to find it.

Ideas?

What I'm expecting:

[image: Expectations]

What I get:

[image: Reality]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The checkboxes are in the section of the webpart view called "Tabular View"

Edit Webpart -> Edit the Current View -> Tabular View Section -> Allow individual item checkboxes

Comment: Bingo! Found it. Thanks. Can this be used with the "newsletter" or "preview pane" styles? it appears not, but I may be missing something.

Comment: No it does not, it works for default views.

Comment: Still a problem, I finally had to resort to grouping presentations via folder. Then when you open the folder, (in the default all items view), the checkboxes show up.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the checkboxes as well. I went to Library Settings > Views/All Documents > Style > Changed to Default View (it was on Basic Table View)

And the checkboxes have returned.